# Did King David lose his adult son during a revolt when he revolted against him as a punishment of King David's adultery?

Tags: biblical-basis, david

King David lost his adult son when he rebelled against him and his Kingdom.

Was this the punishment of God or the curse of God because King David committed adultery and murder and also because he had certain moral responsibilities that he failed to perform before God being the ancestor of God the Son? What does the Bible say about this?

Comment: You obviously know a lot about this incident (from your two questions on the subject). Do you, yourself, have an opinion about this matter ?

Comment: I strongly believe in Bible. Coveting other man's wife is a sin and is wrong.

Comment: @Nigel J And there is a consequence to sin whether it is in the form of curse or punishment of God or anything else. It could be generational as King Ahab was cursed by God.

Comment: _Nathan said unto David, The LORD also hath put away thy sin_ 2 Samuel 12:13. I think, for the sake of balance (and righteousness) you might have included God's response, as well as your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES, as 2 Samuel is quite clear as to why Absalom rebelled against David.  Thus, we don't need to search for a more esoteric / hidden reason such as generational curse.

We can see it as a 2 level reason:

1. From Absalom's point of view, it's because he is dissatisfied with David's inability to exercise judgment correctly: David didn't punish his half brother Amnon for raping his sister ([2 Sam 13:21-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Sam.+13%3A21%E2%80%9322&version=NLT))
   but instead mourned deeply for Amon when Absalom killed Amnon ([2 Sam 13:37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=+2+sam+13%3A37&version=NLT)) and refused to see him ([2 Sam 14:32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=+2+sam+14%3A32&version=NLT)).
2. From God's point of view it's part of God's **specific** punishment of David ([2 Sam 2:10-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Samuel+12%3A10-11&version=NLT)), and is therefore preordained:

   > <sup>10</sup> From this time on, your family will live by the sword because you have despised me by taking Uriah’s wife to be your own.  <sup>11</sup> “This is what the Lord says: Because of what you have done, I will cause your own household to rebel against you. I will give your wives to another man before your very eyes, and he will go to bed with them in public view.

*Source*: section 6.1.1 of [Chapter 6 Absalom's Revolt](https://brill.com/view/book/9789004411722/BP000018.xml) of the 2019 Brill book [A King and a Fool?  The Succession Narrative as a Satire](https://brill.com/view/title/54881) by Virginia Miller.

Note in [2 Sam 12:13-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%2012%3A10-14&version=nlt), that immediately after David repented, God spared David the death penalty he deserved (v. 13) although God didn't let the fruit of David's sin to survive his sickness as punishment (v. 14):

> <sup>13</sup> Then David confessed to Nathan, “I have sinned against the Lord.”  Nathan replied, “Yes, but the Lord has forgiven you, and you won’t die for this sin. <sup>14</sup> Nevertheless, because you have shown utter contempt for the word of the Lord by doing this, your child will die.”

Even so, I don't think the Bible characterizes this as a generational curse, as punishment seems to be given on a case by case basis.

Comment: _Nathan said unto David, The LORD also hath put away thy sin 2 Samuel 12:13._ (Added, for the sake of balance.)

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks.  I incorporated 2 Sam 12:13-14 into the answer as well.